# Filter and include based on two or more strings in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a query/string that I want to do a filter + include to check if that string is matching an item in another array. For example, I have this which works for a single string:

```
const filteredString =  `${this.filter}`.toLowerCase();
     this.filteredCampaigns = this.filteredCampaigns.concat(this.allCampaigns.
            filter((item) => item.description?.toLowerCase().includes(filteredString) ||
            item.type?.toLowerCase().includes(filteredString) ||
            item.code?.toLowerCase().includes(filteredString)
            ));
```

Since I want to match multiple strings, I do a split() in my string to make it to an array and put the strings in separated elements:

```
const filteredString: string = `${this.filter}`.toLowerCase().split(' ');
```

Now thats an array, I make a for-of loop through my filter methods:

```
  for (const val of filteredString) {
            this.filteredCampaigns = this.filteredCampaigns?.concat(this.allCampaigns.
              filter((item) => item.description?.toLowerCase().includes(val) ||
                item.type?.toLowerCase().includes(val) ||
                item.code?.toLowerCase().includes(val)
              ));
          }
        }
```

Problem with above is that it will filter out each element from the array independently from each other. So if my query/filteredString have two string elements, and one of the elements returns a match and the other does not, I will still get a result. But I want ALL of the items in the string to be 'connected' to each other in the filtering, and return all items that partially matches all of the strings in my array. How to do it?

Comment: do you have some data to test?

Answer (score 1):

You could destructure `item` and check if the filter contains one of the value.

```
const
    filter = this.filter.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
    
this.filteredCampaigns = this.allCampaigns.filter(({ description = '', type = '', code = '' }) =>
    [description.toLowerCase(), type.toLowerCase(), code.toLowerCase()]
        .some(word => filter.includes(word))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter string.

```
const filter = 'not that';
```

Space-separated filters.

```
const filteredStrings: string[] = `${filter}`.toLowerCase().split(' ');
```

Assuming your campaign data.

```
const allCampaigns = [{
    description: 'This is ...',
    type: 'TYPE1',
    code: 'TD35'
  },
  {
    description: 'That will be done...',
    type: 'TYPE2',
    code: 'TC33'
  },
  {
    description: 'You shall not pass',
    type: 'UUGG',
    code: 'CD01'
  }
];
```

Filtered campaigns

```
let filteredCampaigns: any[] = [];
```

**Assign  method:**

```
filteredCampaigns = filteredCampaigns?.concat(allCampaigns.filter((item) => filteredStrings.filter(val => item.description?.toLowerCase().includes(val)).length ||
  filteredStrings.filter(val => item.type?.toLowerCase().includes(val)).length ||
  filteredStrings.filter(val => item.code?.toLowerCase().includes(val)).length
));
```

[**Demo**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwDZQKYCcYF4YHIwixQAWAhlLgNwCwAUHaJLIihqgCYDKU6CYA5hABcMaLwEBtALrYYAAwAkAbxZp0AXzkA6KCAAyIAO4YAwqQioAFAEotEAA5IEUS7jzWa9Wo2gxSSJDMAW3tSBH5IWQk6GBglGNiYdlQIYF57KARwEVwAFWIECBhCmC0y3AAaBNioAE97VBzcgE0ABQBRAEZK6phQZKaAEQBmAFZcBPUq2lj4mcTk1PTM7Lx88hhDZCQYACNUJPBUMq0e%20Zr6xrW29oAmM8S%20kAG1k2HhifmphLnHxbSEBksmAcs0QABXURkAIwAiwUIQCAPRJ1Bo5ACq6IA4ljkbF%20ldcCZBgAGbqTOhSTx0JCoZjINQcYKhcKQESkMC1aRRKl0OiqNjsZlhCJFHAC9BM0ghEWQAD8WkYwHIln8gWlLNFWl6j118AZGEslmcqCC1mwAD59axJVweHxBFoJZYAG7%20S3FNBBLT-ZbAhW6AzGdBmCw2LR8YBIcGLV3%20ay2WkCEgwAA%20qZ1et1Eo43HEjudbp2WCtJu9qNQAf0RlM5istkj0djRYTWiT-BT6czWcSObt%20YgToN6DjxdLXsVz0rOmrwdD9YjYCjMZSo9b7ZI3azCep3nAEBAtLbIH4lj7wtZEA8QA)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than concatenating the matches to the array, I would push the matches of each string to it's own array firstly, then check if the amount of matches found is the same number of `filteredStrings`.

If all strings had matches, I reduce the `filteredCampaigns` array from `2D` to `1D`

else, I reset the `filteredCampaigns` to an empty array

```
const filteredString: string = `${this.filter}`.toLowerCase().split(' ');
this.filteredCampaigns = [];

for (const val of filteredStrings) {
  this.filteredCampaigns.push(this.allCampaigns.filter(item => item.description?.toLowerCase().includes(val) || item.type?.toLowerCase().includes(val) || item.code?.toLowerCase().includes(val)))
}

if (this.filteredCampaigns.length == filteredStrings.length) this.filteredCampaigns.flat();
else this.filteredCampaigns = [];
```